# select knife projected edges via python

Tags: python

I have a simple pattern knife projected on to a sphere. is there a way to select the newly projected edges on the sphere via python?
[image]

[image]

Comment: immediately after you apply the knife project they should be selected, so deselecting all and being in edge select mode before applying the project should give you what you want.

Comment: @Marty Fouts  it seems after the projection, it will select what is inside the boundary shape. for example when projecting a circle, it will select all edges inside the projected circle, afterward use select boundary loop can get the edges. but for shapes with internal lines, it is not so.  sample blend file hosted here:https://easyupload.io/tj8oin
so my question could also be how to select newly created edges?